# How to double digits in number

Tags: c

I am having a problem on how to double digits of any number.

For example, the number: 12345 output would be 1122334455 using functions and loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int num;
printf("Please Enter a number");
scanf("%d",&num);
for(int i=0;i<=num%10;i++) {
       if(i==num%10)
             newNum+=i;
for(int i=1;i<=num%10;i++) {
       if(i==num/10%10)
             newNum+=i;
```

Comment: You're having a problem? Well, what problem?

Comment: @Broman if i continue with this **for** it doesnt give me anything cuz i dont know how many digits is the num how i can fix this

Comment: To be honest, I think the best thing you can do is to back a little bit in your exercises. I'm sorry to say it but this exercise seems to be a bit hard for you. You should practice on easier tasks first.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you do not have to store the value with duplicated digits, as storing it as int will quickly overflow. If you have to, you can use long long or an array.

Your for loop does not make sense. You have to loop until all intergers have been duplicated. To do so, determine the ones place with mod 10, then divide number by 10.  It will loop until number is 0. Try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int number;
    int temp;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    while(number) {
        temp = number % 10;
        printf("%d%d", temp, temp);
        number /= 10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not checking the return value of scanf. Always do that.

Comment: With this assumption, you don't even need to do all the stuff doing within `while` loop body. Take input in a `char` array and print every character twice until encounter `\0`.

Comment: @H.S. yes. True.

Comment: @Broman It seems there was an attempt in the post to understand the use of modulus and loops.

Comment: It finally worked, this idea is great for understanding @RJM Thank so much. i used these loops to know if i can use it for a long number like using for until the last digit in the number and asking with **IF** if this digit is equal i print it and so on, that what i mean.

Comment: @MarcelMhmood Good. I am glad it helped. You're welcome.

Comment: @RJM Removed the downvote and posted a question about it in meta that may interest you: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381721/6699433

Comment: @Broman I will read it. Either way for the vote is fine. I like trying to help people (usually apparent students), who seem confused. Most often, they do not articulate their confusion well. Therefore, I try to pinpoint what comes across as the main concept in isolation of the other problems. If it helps, cool. If not, i do not cate about the votes.  I probably should only have shown the loop here.

Comment: It's just that I very often see questions where the return value from scanf is not tested, and I believe that part of the reason is that answers here contain code like yours. IMO you should at least have mentioned it, but maybe removing everything except the loop would be the best.

Comment: @Broman I agree. I basically commented the same on your post. It's a good question and a good point.